# Unable to get xmpp muc room information in android

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, asmack, multiuserchat

I am using asmack library for my chat application.I am using below described code after successful login for getting Muc room information:

> ```
> MultiUserChat mMultiUserChat = new MultiUserChat(connection,"VjNewMoiosandroid@conference.chat");
> mMultiUserChat.join(USERNAME);
> try {     
>   if (mMultiUserChat.isJoined()==true) {                                  
>   RoomInfo roomInfo=mMultiUserChat.getRoomInfo(connection,"VjNewMoiosandroid@conference.chat");}
>
>                           } catch (Exception e) {
>                               // TODO: handle exception
>
>                               e.printStackTrace();
>                           }
> ```

I get this error while getting room information ,while i debug and check i am getting room information in   log but nothing comes in roomInfo.

> 10-10 08:55:12.388: W/System.err(1821): java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.jivesoftware.smack.util.PacketParserUtils$2 cannot be cast to
>   org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.DiscoverInfo 10-10 08:55:12.428:
>   W/System.err(1821):   at
>   org.jivesoftware.smackx.ServiceDiscoveryManager.discoverInfo(ServiceDiscoveryManager.java:600)
>   10-10 08:55:12.458: W/System.err(1821):   at
>   org.jivesoftware.smackx.ServiceDiscoveryManager.discoverInfo(ServiceDiscoveryManager.java:552)
>   10-10 08:55:12.478: W/System.err(1821):   at
>   com.demo.xmppchat.CopyOfXMPPChatDemoActivity.getRoomInfo(CopyOfXMPPChatDemoActivity.java:469)

My chat room information i received in log

```
10-10 15:38:10.133: D/SMACK(26035): 03:38:10 PM RCV  (1107887640): <iq 
from='VjNewMoiosandroid@conference.chat' to='14393671556301070000@chat/Smack' 
id='VWaeO-6' type='result'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'><identity 
category='conference' type='text' name='VjNewMoiosandroid'/><feature var='
http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'/><feature var='muc_public'/><feature 
var='muc_persistent'/><feature var='muc_open'/><feature var='muc_semianonymous'/><feature 
var='muc_moderated'/><feature var='muc_unsecured'/><x xmlns='jabber:x:data' 
type='result'><field type='hidden' var='FORM_TYPE'><value>
http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#roominfo</value></field><field label='Room description' 
var='muc#roominfo_description'><value></value></field><field label='Number of occupants' 
var='muc#roominfo_occupants'><value>1</value></field></x></query></iq>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using old asmack jar that is my issue ,I made some changes i used MultiUserChat class getRoomInfo() Method directly in my class

> ```
> MultiUserChat mMultiUserChat = new MultiUserChat(connection,"VjNewMoiosandroid@conference.chat");
> mMultiUserChat.join(USERNAME);
> try {     
>   if (mMultiUserChat.isJoined()==true) {                                  
>   String roomInfo=getRoomInfo(connection, "VjNewMoiosandroid@conference.chat");}
>
>                           } catch (Exception e) {
>                               // TODO: handle exception
>
>                               e.printStackTrace();
>                           }
> ```

I made one method as below

> ```
> public static String getRoomInfo(Connection connection, String room)
>               throws XMPPException {
>        String roomInfo="";
>        try {
>             ServiceDiscoveryManager serviceDiscoveryManager=new ServiceDiscoveryManager(connection);
>             DiscoverInfo info = serviceDiscoveryManager.discoverInfo(room);
>             roomInfo=info.toXML();
>
>       } catch (XMPPException e) {
>           // TODO: handle exception
>           Log.e("xmpp", e.toString());
>
>       }
>
>           return  roomInfo;
>       }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Do this way

Replace this line

```
RoomInfo roomInfo=mMultiUserChat.getRoomInfo(connection,"VjNewMoiosandroid@conference.chat");
```

With this

```
RoomInfo roomInfo=MultiUserChat.getRoomInfo(connection,"VjNewMoiosandroid@conference.chat");
```

Comment: Hello Biraj thanks for reply i did as u said but receiving same error